# Sparse files in WinXP SP3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, filesystems

Suddenly, we found out that WinXP SP3 didn't allow to create NTFS sparse file **in user-mode application**. Namely, `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_SET_SPARSE` returns with error 0x57 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`). The same code works well in SP2. Also, it's all ok if make the same calls from kernel-mode (both in SP3 and SP2).

Google says nothing about this. Has anyone met this problem or even have some additional info about it?

Comment: Are you using FSCTL_SET_SPARSE etc? More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365566(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, of course.
In usermode, DeviceIoControl with FSCTL_SET_SPARSE returns with error 0x57 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) under WinXP SP3 and works well under WinXP SP2.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse files are working fine for me in WinXP SP3. What is the value of GetLastError after the call to CreateFile? Or after DeviceIoControl if that is what you are using?

This site has some good info on sparse files: http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/sparse-files.phtml

The MSDN documentation is a given.

Comment: Hi Adzm, it's interesting that it behaves differently. We get an 0x57 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) after DeviceIoControl (added these details into the question text). But, it happens only when we try to create sparse file in user mode, in kernel mode it works well.
Thanks for the link.